# DOM VBA IE11 Automate Placing Orders on a Website - Trouble With Pop Up iFrame for Picture Upload

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, dom, iframe

We have a Virtual Assistant placing hundreds of orders for ball markers on this site: https://www.golfballs.com/Golf-Misc/Tools/Classic-Photo-Poker-Chips-3-Pack.htm

I had used VBA before to get data from a website but I would like to use it to automate the placing of orders. I can get close but there are a few things tripping me up. Here is one such thing.

[image: ball marker order page]

When we click the "Upload a Photo" button here, an iFrame pops up. We cannot get the the focus onto the items in the iFrame. The items that we need to work are:

[image: upload area]

1. Clicking the copyright box (id = copyright_check)
2. Clicking the Choose File button and giving it a path to a local drive picture (id = fileField)
3. Clicking Upload (id = upload)

Here is what we got so far that makes the pop up open, but we can't do things inside the pop up. Next question if this one is answered is to then go to the next pop up and click Save (id = saveBtn). Once we got that, I can automate the rest of the cart and checkout.

```
Sub SelectColorForGolfballs()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim objWindow As Object
Dim browser As Object
Dim url As String
Dim nodeColorDropDown As Object
Dim nodeThreeButtons As Object
Dim browserPopUp As Object
Dim nodeFrames As Object
Dim nodeIframeDoc As Object

  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  url = "https://www.golfballs.com/Golf-Misc/Tools/Classic-Photo-Poker-Chips-3-Pack.htm"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

  'Select color from dropdown
  Set nodeColorDropDown = browser.document.getElementByID("2")
  nodeColorDropDown.selectedIndex = 6 'Pink for testing
  Call TriggerEvent(browser.document, nodeColorDropDown, "change")
  'Manual break for loading the page complitly
  'Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(pause_hours, pause_minutes, pause_seconds))
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))

  'Open Picture Upload
  'The document changed, so you can't work with the old document here
  'In a first step you need the div element with the three buttons
  'we get in the last step by trigger dropdown event
  '
  '&lt;div class="options-gallery"&gt;
  '  &lt;a href="javascript:productSelection(1, 'P');"&gt;
  '    &lt;img src="https://d1tp32r8b76g0z.cloudfront.net/images/property/button/Half/Condition_P.jpg" title="Personalized" border="0"&gt;
  '  &lt;/a&gt;
  '  &lt;a href="javascript:productSelection(1, 'S');"&gt;
  '    &lt;img src="https://d1tp32r8b76g0z.cloudfront.net/images/property/button/Half/Condition_S.jpg" title="Photo" border="0"&gt;
  '  &lt;/a&gt;
  '  &lt;a href="javascript:productSelection(1, 'L');"&gt;
  '    &lt;img src="https://d1tp32r8b76g0z.cloudfront.net/images/property/button/Half/Condition_L.jpg" title="Novelty" border="0"&gt;
  '  &lt;/a&gt;
  '&lt;/div&gt;
  Set nodeThreeButtons = browser.document.getElementsByClassName("options-gallery")(0)

  'The second button must be clicked
  nodeThreeButtons.FirstChild.NextSibling.Click
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))

  'Focus popup by runnig throuhg all open windows
  For Each objWindow In objShell.Windows
    'Check if it's an IE
    If InStr(1, UCase(objWindow.FullName), "IEXPLORE") > 0 Then
      'Check if it's the right IE
      If InStr(1, objWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("title")(0).innertext, "iCusomize Image Selection") Then
        Set browserPopUp = objWindow
        Exit For
      End If
    End If
  Next objWindow

  'Now we can work with the popup
  'It has only short code over all and a very short body
  'You have to access the content of an iFrame
  '
  'Problem: I don't know why the following don't work
  'I know it can't be in the same line
  'You must split the access to the iFrame
  'Get a node collection of all frames/ iframes of the document
  Set nodeFrames = browserPopUp.document.frames

  'The following line couses the error "Access denied"
  'Select the first (and only) frame from the node collection
  Set nodeIframeDoc = nodeFrames(0).document

  'Check the copyright checkbox
  nodeIframeDoc.getElementByID("copyright_check").Click

  'If you are at this point we can look ahead
End Sub
```

And this procedure to trigger the event

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

With the help of @zwenn code above was written for the first part of the question. This new question is separated out as the original part 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DOM VBA IE11 Automate Placing Orders on a Website - Trouble With OnChange and Picture Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113561/dom-vba-ie11-automate-placing-orders-on-a-website-trouble-with-onchange-and-pi)

Comment: @braX An [edit] is probably need to clarify.  It is part of the same overall problem but part 1, selecting a colour, was solved by zwenn in a prior question (your linked one). The code above is to highlight a part 2 problem, the basis of this question, which is about interacting with the upload box. I believe the code shown is a starting point from zwenn / OP. However, a good edit of both code and question would be help clarify this.

Comment: Or edit to the related question to make clearer......

Comment: With the help of @zwenn code above was written for the first part of the question. This new question is separated out as the original part 2.