Excel VBA IE click open a new window and nothing happens, with no error too
Despite I'm just an entusiast absolutelly non pro, I'm using with moderate success an Excel vba code to fill some forms of an intranet company procedure written in html/java and download some data files. Unfortunatelly it is a private procedure with access limited to the intranet members, that's my worry.
The problem occurs when I have to select the "start" and "end" of a date range. To do that, I need to press a button that open a new window. In the new window I should be able to set the date and the frequency (monthly or daily). The problem is that after the simple command that opens the window:
IE.Document.getElementById("idAvanzDateButton").onclick
the window opens correctly, but I havent the return to the VBA and I cannot debug or excute the rest of the lines. I donno if I must listen and trigger some event; but it is very sure that I loose the control after ".onclick"  without the possibility to do something else.
Here the code html of the button got from the intranet page:
<input type="button" id="idAvanzDateButton" onclick="impostazioneAvanzataDate()" value="Impostazione avanzata" class="custom_button_midlarge">

Here my code to reach that point, but it's very basic and still on test:
Sub ADVANCED_DATE()

'----WE START WITH INTERET EXPLORER---
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = True
    'Define URL
url = "https://moct0.sede.corp.company.com:35779/scriptMoct0/ncg/datamart/interrogazionedinamica/start.do"
 
IE.navigate url

 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:07")
  While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
  
'******************
'giving input to start:
IE.Document.getElementById("idSocieta").Value = "01" 'it is the first clone to analyse
IE.Document.getElementById("idsocieta").FireEvent ("onchange")
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")


'here I press the "Advanced date range" that is a button that open a new window
IE.Document.getElementById("idAvanzDateButton").Click

'the new window opens correctly, the address is now different and it's like this:
'https://moct0.sede.corp.company.com:35779/scriptMoct0/ncg/datamart/interrogazionedinamica/dgl405.do?codiceSocieta=01&elencoSocieta=

'here it stops; it doesn't give any kind of error but doesn't respond to any command and I cannot debug too with F8. So I haven't the return to the VBA and any line that follow is not executed. I'm stuck.

IE.Document.getElementById("idDataContabile").Value = "04.06.2024" 'this input, that is necessary ,isn't processed

'here follow the other input...

'I need help :) .....

End Sub

'I tried to interact with the child window using this method (here), but as stated above, nothing is processed after the button and the new window that opens. So it's useless at the moment, till I cannot go on.
I thank you in advance for your kind advices :)

Support for IE is no more. Which OS are you using.
Also see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/solved-whats-going-to-happen-to-microsoft-internet/32e237e9-39f7-43da-ab37-0043f3e92ca4

I agree with @CHill60 IE is outdated and should no longer be used. So you should find another solution (SeleniumBasic). As a workaround: It sounds like another window opens that then doesn't have the focus. How such windows can be found you can read in an older post of mine here (at the comment 'Focus popup by runnig throuhg all open windows) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113561/dom-vba-ie11-automate-placing-orders-on-a-website-trouble-with-onchange-and-pi/59115782#59115782

@CHill60 It's on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19045

There's your problem. You need to find an alternative to using IE - try Selenium, I believe it's free (not proven)
